# Запятая перед И в предложении

Tags: запятые, ссп

Пожалуйста, подскажите, нужна ли запятая перед И в предложении "После   завершения   установки  нажмите  А(,) и на экране отобразится установленное время"

Comment: «Нажмите А(,) тогда на экране отобразится...». Нужна запятая?

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос об общем второстепенном члене довольно сложен и неоднозначен, поэтому я допускаю **два варианта оформления.**

(1) ***После завершения установки** // нажмите А и на экране отобразится установленное время.* Нет паузы и запятой.

(2) ***После завершения установки нажмите А**, и на экране отобразится установленное время.* Делается пауза и ставится запятая.

В принципе автор сам решает, каким образом он учитывает причинно-следственную связь между событиями.

**В первом случае** после установки (общего члена) события мыслятся как одновременные и однородные (нажали А и отобразилось время).

**Во втором случае** мы одним событием считаем установку и нажатие А, а далее как следствие отображается установленное время.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ** от 19.02.2022 г. (дополнительое пояснение **к комментарию**)

Вы слишком привязаны к конкретным событиям, а здесь нужно рассуждать **абстрактно.** У нас **три события**, связанные причинно-следственной связью и следующие одно за другим: установка (программы), нажатие А, отображение времени.

Предложений у нас только два, поэтому надо объединить события в две группы.

Разумнее всего предположить, что **установка требует определенного времени,** в то время как два следующих события происходят с очень малым интервалом, так что условно их можно считать **одновременными и однородными**.  Мы связываем их союзом И, а установку считаем для них общим событием, то есть общим второстепенным членом.

**Поэтому более логичен вариант (1)**: После завершения установки // нажмите А и на экране отобразится установленное время. Нет паузы и запятой.

**Во втором варианте** мы связываем установку и нажатие кнопки в одно событие, а далее устанавливается время **как конечный результат наших действий**: (2) После завершения установки нажмите А, и на экране отобразится установленное время как конечный результат.

Comment: Нет, там прямая зависимость. Время не отобразится после установки, если не нажать. То есть там следствие, без запятой нельзя. Или у вас время отобразится в любом случае? Лишь тогда можно без запятой.

Comment: Вот здесь надо чуть-чуть логики. Её отсутствие не совместимо с наукой.

Comment: Вот тут я согласен с oleedd. Сравните: Вечером я вышел из дома, и на меня обрушился дождь (запятая просится), Вечером я шёл домой и на меня обрушился дождь (запятая не просится). Почему? Во втором случае сочетание несовершенного и совершенного глагола, думаю, дело в этом. Вечером я шёл домой и на меня рушился ливень — тут вообще гладко (видимо, потому что два протяжённых, то есть одновременных события).

Comment: Я поняла вашу мысль, только считаю, что значимость видовых форм  для РЕАЛЬНОГО обозначения причиннно-следственных событий должна быть раскрыта в ответе, тогда и лишних вопросов не будет  (в вашем втором примере видовые формы разные., поэтому он не слишком убедителен).  Ну и привет oleedd, а также всей логике и науке в его лице.  Я не исключаю, что он весь состоит из логики,  но желательно научиться выражать ее словами (а иначе чего она стоит).

Comment: @Sharon Давайте пройдёмся по принципу комбинаторики по всем вариантам. Совершенный + несовершенный: "Вечером я вышел на улицу, и на меня падал ливень" , невозможная комбинация. Св + св: Вечером я вышел на улицу, и на меня рухнул ливень (последовательность, зпт просится). Нсв + св: "Вечером я шёл по улице(,) и на меня рухнул ливень" (так-сяк звучит, что с зпт, что без неё). Нсв + нсв: "Вечером я шёл по улице и на меня падал ливень" (идеально без зпт, поскольку протяжённые параллельные события).

Comment: Пройдемся, возможно, но чуть позже, сейчас у меня немного другие планы.

Comment: Однородность прежде всего заключается в независимости. А здесь условие: если нажмёте, то тогда отобразится время. Да без разницы, какой между ними интервал, важно то, что второе возникнет только при наличии первого. Здесь тоже не поставите запятую? *После завершения установки нажмите А(,) и тогда на экране отобразится установленное время.* А ведь это слово подразумевается. Вот более похожий пример с дождём: *Вечером [этим] выйди из дома, и намокнешь под дождём.* Объединение при глаголе в повелительном наклонении вообще невозможно. Найдите хоть один такой пример в справочниках.

Comment: @oleedd   «После завершения установки нажимаем А и считываем с экрана установленное время». Нужна запятая? Грамматические формы одинаковые, поэтому предложения однородные? А как же семантика (если нажмёте, то только тогда отобразится время)? Ведь считать время мы можем только после нажатия А: нажимаем, потом считываем. Причинно-следственные отношения остались те же, а запятую не ставим? Или ставим?

Comment: А здесь общее подлежащее "мы" подразумевается, поэтому здесь не надо. А грамматическая форма имеет влияние, об этом сказано у Розенталя. Да и мысль в том, что время отобразится после нажатия, а не после установки (в чём нет смысла, ведь и так понятно, что программа может работать только после установки).

Comment: Мы сейчас говорим об однородности двух событий (нажали кнопку – считали время), не надо сюда примешивать все остальное. Отношения причинно-следственные, зависимые, а мы их считаем однороднымии как бы независимыми Тогда чего стоят ваши рассуждения на эту тему? Поменяли грамматическую форму, а семантика как бы и ни при чем, не так ли?

Comment: "Считали время" и "время отобразилось" — разные вещи. Давайте рассматривать сложносочинённые предложения, а не простые. В вашем примере и без общего элемента можно без запятой: *Нажимаем А и считываем с экрана установленное время.* Здесь на слух не особо улавливается следствие, потому что не звучит так, что время появляется конкретно после нажатия. А потому, что о появлении не сказано. Проблема ещё в повелительном наклонении, найдите хоть один пример с ним. Но и здесь нужна запятая: *После завершения установки нажали А, и на экране отобразилось установленное время.*

Comment: Ладно, спасибо, все выяснили. Однородность не связана напрямую с причинно-следственными отношениями. У Кустовой однородные отношения связываются с перечислительной интонацией,  существенным призаком явлется равноправие, равнозначность. Даже видовые формы могут не совпадать, например:  Дышать стало легче, и голоса под липами звучали мягче.  События могут быть связанными, но автор может не обозначать эту связь, если она неочевидана и не важна.

Comment: Про перечислительную интонацию сказано в точку, при ней нет смысловых связей. Из-за следствия порой иная грамматическая форма, а от неё уже однородность точно зависит напрямую. Вот похожие примеры: *Сейчас дай мне деньги, и дам тебе товар. Сегодня добудь оленя в лесу, и поедим свежего, вкусного мяса.* В таких случаях запятая обязательна. Причин как минимум три: следствие, условие, повелительное наклонение (совсем другая форма). И следствие на последнем месте.

Comment: @oleedd А такой вопрос.  (1) После установки нажимаем А и считываем  время. Здесь односоставные предложения, их можно приравнять к однородным сказуемым, запятая не ставится. (2) После установки  нажимается А и считывается время. Это уже двусоставные предложения в составе ССП. Предложения однородные, независимые? Как насчет запятой?

Comment: Не односоставные, а простое: *После установки [мы] нажимаем А и считываем время.* Это как в: *Берём деньги и идём в магазин.* Не особо здесь следствие есть. В них один производитель действия, поэтому простые. (2) реально искусственное, его не применить, ведь имеется в виду то, что можно нажать, а не что нажимается в обязательном порядке. Но там уже запятая уместнее. В примере из вопроса два подлежащих, а в ваших нет, на это обратите внимание.

Comment: Нажимается кнопка А – это какое предложение? Или: дома строятся. И еще: Односоставные предложения считаются простыми, если имеют общий распространитель (из грамматики). Так что ваше "Берём деньги и идём в магазин" не прокатит. Это односоставные предложения.

Comment: Вы мои предложения рассмотрите, те уже рассмотрели. Нажимается кнопка А – это какое предложение? Или: дома строятся. Это двусоставные предложения?  (А определения (односоставные предложения/однородные члены) вы, конечно, сами сочиняете. Или прочитали где?)

Comment: У Розенталя сказано, что запятая не ставится, если один производитель. Потому что тогда простое предложение. Да, двусоставные.

Comment: (Это Розенталь говорит о запятых, а не об однородных членах,  не надо мешать грамматику и пунктуацию.) Если предложения двусоставные, то рассмотрим "После установки нажимается кнопка А и считывается время".  Они однородные и независимые, запятой нет?

Comment: Запятые связаны с количеством грамматических основ, а подлежащее может либо быть, либо подразумеваться. В (2) запятая очень желательна, но не обязательна, как в примере из вопроса, потому что там один производитель действия (он подразумевается). Не нравится мне ваш пример, он плохой, совсем не факт, что после установки кнопка нажмётся.

Comment: Вы определенно-личные предложения знаете? "Сижу дома". Это односоставное предложение, восстанавливать подлежащее не надо. А мне не нравятся ваши "здесь подставляем, там подразумевается" и ваши уклончивые ответы. Не грамматика, а "страна неопределенная".  Просто не хотите признать очевидную вещь:  реальная взаимообусловленность может не учитываться в предложении, если в этом нет необходимости.

Comment: 1) *Читает книгу и ест шоколадку.* 2) *Он читает книгу и ест шоколадку.* Почему в первом случае считать сложным предложением, а во втором простым? Вам не кажется это странным? Ведь ни смысл, ни интонация не меняется.

Comment: Обычно можно не учитывать, хотя часто это плохо. Но здесь: 1) не может быть однородности с повелительным наклонением; 2) глупо говорить об отображении времени после завершения установки, и так понятно, что программа будет работать только после установки, смысл как раз в следствии.

Comment: В определенно-личных предложениях  субъект действия участвует в речевом контакте; Я – это говорящий, ТЫ, ВЫ – адресат, собеседник. Третье лицо без подлежащего не позволяет реконструировать субъект действия, предложение неполное, восстанавливается из контекста. Про повелительное наклонение все давно забыли (это, кстати, тоже определенно-личное предложение). И реальную семантику не надо мешать с грамматикой. Ладно, спасибо за беседу, до новых встреч.

Comment: Необходимость зависит не от желания, а от других факторов. Не нужно реконструировать субъект действия, важно то, тот же он или другой.

Answer (score 0):

Это сложносочинённое предложение, части которого не имеют общего элемета. Поэтому запятая перед 'И', конечно, нужна.

Comment: А разве "после завершения установки" не является общим второстепенным членом?

Comment: @Ирина нет, этот обстоятельственный оборот относится к первому сказуемому — "нажмите".